# Delete files from HDFS path having date suffixed to the HDFS path older than a given date | unix

Tags: shell, unix, hdfs

I have HDFS path having files as below -

```
/test/abc/xyz/2018-01-01
/test/abc/xyz/2019-01-01
/test/abc/xyz/2020-01-01
/test/abc/xyz/2020-02-01
/test/abc/xyz/2020-03-01
```

How can I delete files older than a date  say 2020-01-01 in shell script

Final output -

```
/test/abc/xyz/2020-01-01
/test/abc/xyz/2020-02-01
/test/abc/xyz/2020-03-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for fn in /test/abc/xyz/*
do  
 if [ $(tr -d '-' <<<$fn) -gt 20200101 ] 
 then 
   echo $fn; 
 fi
done
```